# Reactstrap Date Input - Block Keyboard

Tags: reactjs, input, reactstrap

Using [Reactstrap](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap) and more importantly, using the Input (with a type of "date")

```
<Input type="date" name="date" 
    onChange={this.setStart}
    style={{backgroundColor:"white",marginTop:10,height:50}}
    value={this.state.order.start_date}
    defaultValue={this.state.order.start_date}
    id="exampleDate" placeholder={translate("Start Date")} />
```

This generates an Input box with a calendar icon on the right side of the box. Clicking the icon pops up a calendar widget for the user to select. The wrinkle is that I would like to block the user's ability to change the date through the keyboard (preventing them from entering an invalid date).  I have tried a couple of approaches using onKey* but with no luck. How would I prevent a user from changing the date through the keyboard (relying completely on the widget)?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
onKeyDown={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); }}
```